# Error when trying to setup webpack to compile my jsx app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx, babeljs

I am trying to setup webpack with react.js to compile my jsx app. When running webpack from the command line in the  directory, webpack seems to compile the app without errors in terminal. The problem is that a file in {my-project-path}/public/index.html is produced with the following content shown below (actual path on my filesystem is replaced with my-project-path in this snippet):

```
    Html Webpack Plugin:
    <pre>

    Error: Child compilation failed:
      Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '<my-project-path>/index.html' in '<my-project-path>':
      Error: Can't resolve '<my-project-path>/index.html' in '<my-project-path>'

      - compiler.js:76 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/compiler.js:76:16

      - Compiler.js:298 Compiler.<anonymous>
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:298:10

      - Compiler.js:516 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:516:13

      - Tapable.js:138 next
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:138:11

      - CachePlugin.js:62 Compiler.<anonymous>
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5

      - Tapable.js:142 Compiler.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:142:13

      - Compiler.js:513 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:513:10

      - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

      - Compilation.js:655 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:655:19

      - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

      - Compilation.js:646 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:646:11

      - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

      - Compilation.js:641 self.applyPluginsAsync.err
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:641:10

      - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

      - Compilation.js:637 sealPart2
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:637:9

      - Tapable.js:131 Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:131:46

      - Compilation.js:580 Compilation.seal
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:580:8

      - Compiler.js:510 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:510:16

      - Tapable.js:225 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[tapable]/lib/Tapable.js:225:11

      - Compilation.js:482 _addModuleChain
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:482:11

      - Compilation.js:371 Compilation.errorAndCallback
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:371:4

      - Compilation.js:392 moduleFactory.create
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/Compilation.js:392:12

      - NormalModuleFactory.js:247 factory
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:247:20

      - NormalModuleFactory.js:65 resolver
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:65:21

      - NormalModuleFactory.js:138 asyncLib.parallel
        [stripe_complex_example]/[webpack]/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:138:21

      - async.js:3861 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[async]/dist/async.js:3861:9

      - async.js:421 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[async]/dist/async.js:421:16

      - async.js:996 iteratorCallback
        [stripe_complex_example]/[async]/dist/async.js:996:13

      - async.js:906 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[async]/dist/async.js:906:16

      - async.js:3858 
        [stripe_complex_example]/[async]/dist/async.js:3858:13
```

My webpack.config.js file is:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/client/client.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: __dirname + '/public'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./public/index.html')],
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My .babelrc file is

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

My project structure is:

```
/client
    /components
        ....
    client.js
/node_modules
/public
    bundle.js
    index.html
.babelrc
.env
.gitignore
package.json
server.js
webpack.config.js
```

My package.json file is

```
{
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "pug": "",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "stripe": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  }
}
```

To summarize the problem, the html page being generated by webpack simply contains a stack trace of errors although webpack doesn't report any errors on the command line. I followed steps in various tutorials to get a node/webpack/react application working, but the devOps part of it is really difficult. Note that tweaks such as using babel-loader instead of file loader give the same result. Could it be because my settings are looking for something produced at '{my-project-path}/index.html' when in fact index.html is produced inside the public folder? If so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This part `require.resolve('./public/index.html')` should be excluded from the following:

```
module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/, require.resolve('./public/index.html')],
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

the 'test' part is a regex match, which checks for files ending with .jsx, therefore excluding an html file is redundant